Temperature compensation when measuring pH and how to calibrate
We want to measure the pH of liquid solutions (impure water) with a sensor that returns a voltage (by measuring the difference of potential inside and outside a glass bulb). The manufacturer provided a formula to transform the voltage into pH. You can make a two-point calibration with two solutions that have known values (pH 4 and 7) at 25°C, and these two mV readings go into the formula, changing an offset and a slope.
The water bodies that we want to measure will be colder, however, and the challenge is now to compensate the temperature (the sensor doesn’t do it for us).
With my last chemistry lessons decades ago, I am now wondering how to go about it.
I did some series to measure the change of output voltage depending on the temperature for different samples (not the mentioned buffer solutions).
Does it make sense to compensate the temperature of a measurement by first using these series to calculate the equivalent voltage that the same sample would have yielded at 25°C and then applying the formula with the two points from a calibration that I performed at 25°C? Or should the calibration happen with buffer solutions that have known pH values for the temperature that I am measuring? Or is there an easier solution?
Just to mention: The measurements should be comparable across various water bodies and of the same water body at different times of the year, so it doesn’t help us to record each pH value with its corresponding T.
Thanks!

There must be a protocol for measuring environmental pH. Here is the EPA, it is not very helpful: https://www.epa.gov/sites/default/files/2017-07/documents/field_ph_measurement100_af.r4.pd
My procedure would be:  The pH meter should measure millivolts to 0.1mv and pH to +/-.001 unit This almost ensures accuracy to 0.01 pH units The electrode the best quality glass electrode affordable with a separate flowing double junction silver chloride reference electrode.  Fill solution for the flow, saturated or 3M KCl.
Daily lab calibration: I recommend Fisher color coded pH 7 and 4 buffers. Zero the meter in pH 7 buffer to the appropriate pH at the temperature. Record the pH, T, and absolute millivolts rinse and blot the electrodes and set the slope with pH 4 buffer using the slope or temperature control NOT the calibrate or zero. Again record pH and absolute mv readings; the difference in the mv readings should be almost 180 mv. The reason for recording mv values is to quality check the system. the value will drift very slowly over weeks or months any sudden jump means a problem with the electrodes, meter or buffers; troubleshoot and repair. A good electrode should be linear from pH 1 to about 11.
Field use: Package several small bottles of 7 and 4 buffer. equilibrate a 7 in the source and measure the pH it should match the buffer at least to +/- 0.01 no need to calibrate if it reads correctly. Equilibrate a 4 buffer and set the slope measure the mv and T; eventually the position of the slope control at the various temperature can be determined and marked. Measure the sample recording mv, pH and T and pertinent data. It might be informative to return the filled sample bottle to the lab and remeasure the pH at lab T with a freshly calibrated system.
The pH depends on the acids etc. present in the water. The various ionizations depend on the temperature. The second factor is the RT in the Nernst equation This is controlled by the slope of the meter.

Thank you for your detailed reply! So, it basically means to recheck calibration in the field with the same buffer solutions that need to have the same temperature as the sample? (PS: There seems to be an "f" missing at the end of your link.)
